# Captura de pantalla en android

Tags: java, android, screenshot

¿Alguien sabe como se puede tomar una captura de pantalla solo oprimiendo la pantalla?

En el layout solo tengo un VideoView y quiero tomar captura de lo que capta en ese momento

Comment: Encendido - Volumen abajo, al mismo tiempo. Esto no es relacionado a programación Migue :)

Comment: @Elenasys parece que si tiene que ver con programación. Usa la tag java y se refiere en el control VideoView

Comment: No porque comente un elemento  de la UI significa que tiene que ser programación, @MigueTorres Migue, quieres tomar screenshot de toda la pantalla? O únicamente tu Layout y elementos contenidos dentro?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tu objeto es poder hacerlo por código.
Sobre el view con que el que quieras trabajar deberias hacer los siguientes:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
```

Con esto ya puedes llamar una vez al método getDrawingCache que te devuelve un bitmap de la imagen para terminar desactivando lo anterior, sería así:

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Un par de consejos, primero ejecutar en segundo plano, depende del dispositivo puede ser mas o menos costoso la operación, tambien para almecenarlo, en ocasiones el bitmap que te devolvera getDrawingCache puede ser null, tendras que tratarlo.

**Edito**:
Claro el siguiente paso sería guardar el bitmap a un fichero sería así:

```
        File mypath = new File(directory, fileName + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            if (!mypath.exists()) mypath.createNewFile();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bitmapImage.recycle();
```

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a las opciones que tienes de compresion y tipo de formato en la documentación. Por cierto el añadido de Fran es muy recomendable.
Por cierto si no has vas a usar mas el bitmap te recomiendo que uses recycle para liberar recursos, muy util para movil con pocos recursos

Comment: ok Cifus, esto guarda un bitmap en caché verdad... en ese momento no está guardado como un archivo jpg o png? por ejemplo

Comment: Así es, aunque si utilizas una versión mas moderna de Android te recomiendo usar pixelcopy

Answer (score 1):

Muy parecido a lo que comenta Cifus, pero forzando un redibujado de la vista, con un *invalidate*. Aquí *view* sería el layout que quieres capturar:

```
  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  view.buildDrawingCache();
  view.invalidate();
  final Bitmap bmp =  view.getDrawingCache();
  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
  view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar la pantalla por código en Android, se puede llamar a la siguiente función, desde una actividad.

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
  try {
    // crear un bitmap con la captura de pantalla
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Para guardar la captura de pantalla, bastaría con llamar a la siguiente función, pasando como parámetro el Bitmap que devuelve la función que obtiene la captura.

```
private void saveScreenshot(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Date now = new Date();
  android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

  try {
    // nombre y ruta de la imagen a incluir
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

  } catch (Throwable e) {
    // Captura los distintos errores que puedan surgir
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

https://trellat.es/capturar-la-pantalla-por-codigo-en-android/